# Why do Hindu Gods and Goddess have navel?

Tags: vishnu, identification-request, brahma

I know its a weird question but it came to my mind today. Whenever we see an image or idol of any Devi-Devta , we can see that they have navel or belly button. Biologically, Navel is associated with our umbilical cord but since Hindu Gods are ayonija i.e. not born from a womb, why are they shown with navels? In the scriptures, there is a story where Bramha came from the navel of Vishnu. Why do they have navel?

Comment: One may ask also: Why do Hindu Gods and Goddesses have a human body? Biologically, a Human body is subject to need of air, water, food and is very much limited to a small portion of the Earth.